# Console color issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python program with a header that is meant to be colored blue.
I am using the art library to generate text and some color codes but things just don't make sense.

Here is the code for the program font-test.py

```
from art import *
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
hStdOut = kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)
mode = ctypes.c_ulong()
kernel32.GetConsoleMode(hStdOut, ctypes.byref(mode))
mode.value |= 4
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, mode)


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

Art=text2art(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}COOL HEADER{bcolors.ENDC}",font='graffiti',chr_ignore=True) # Return ASCII text with block font
print(Art)
```

This is the output from running >> python font-test.py
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Ooc.png)
I expected it to simply print the text "COOL HEADER" in blue.

Comment: `text2art` doesn't support colors.

Comment: is there any library that supports colors

Comment: Try `print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}{Art}{bcolors.ENDC}")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `text2art` you can generate the string. If you want to print this string in a different color, you can do this in the `print()` function, as shown below:

```
Art=text2art("COOL HEADER",font='graffiti',chr_ignore=True)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + Art + bcolors.ENDC)
```